# replace string one with instance of second string remove and replaced with third string without using replaceAll

Tags: java, string, replace

This is what I came up with, but the last test case doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
public class tester
{
   public static String replaceAll(String a, String b, String c){
        for(;;){
           int i = a.indexOf(b);
            if(i==-1){
                break;
            }
            a = a.substring(0,i)+ c + a.substring(i + b.length());
        }
        return a;

       }

       public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(replaceAll("hello my friend, how are you?", "h", "y"));
        System.out.println(replaceAll("CS221 is great!!","great","awesome"));
        System.out.println(replaceAll("aaaa","a","aaa"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm reading your code right:

1. Seeks "a" in "aaaa".  Finds it at index zero.
2. Adds "aaa" to the start of "aaaa" yielding "aaaaaaa".
3. Seeks "a" in "aaaaaaa".  Finds it at index zero.
4. Adds "aaa" to "aaaaaaa" yielding "aaaaaaaaaa".
   ...

So the string will keep growing indefinitely.  You could look into updating the search index by the length of the inserted text to make sure you don't explode your strings like this.

Also, if you're going to be doing a lot of string concatenation, I'd recommend using a `StringBuilder` to prevent loads of copying.

Which is to say that something like this should work:

```
public static String replaceAll(String a, String b, String c){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int i = 0;
    while(i < a.length()){
        int j = a.indexOf(b, i);
        if(j == -1){
            sb.append(a.substring(i, a.length()));
            i = a.length();
        } else {
            sb.append(a.substring(i, j));
            sb.append(c);
            i = j + b.length();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

EDIT - added solution.

Comment: What it is supposed to do is read the first string and then read the first "a"and replace that with three a's. Then do that three more times.          so for the last method call to replaceAll("aaaa","a","aaa"). It should print out as "aaaaaaaaaaaa"

Comment: Updated my answer to provide a solution in code.  It looks good for those three cases, but it may not be completely correct.

Comment: Is there a way to writ this code without the StringBuilder. We haven't gone over StringBuilders in class yet. Otherwise can you explain it so I understand what the .append method is doing. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: `StringBuilder` basically does string concatenation without the penalty of copying the entire string. You can think of it as holding a list of strings in memory, and only joining them together when you call `toString()`.  So you can just start a temporary string and append to it as you go with `+`, and then return it as your output at the end.